# Magento 1.9.0.1 RWD Layered Navigation

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Right now I just switched to the RWD theme in the new Magento 1.9.0.1 and layered navigation no longer shows up. Not in any layout view (1 column, 2 column l/r, or 3 column). But in any old theme it shows up just fine.

I checked the catalog.xml file and found it calling the layered navigation with this:

```
<reference name="left_first">
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="catalog.leftnav.state.renderers" as="state_renderers" />
        </block>
</reference>
```

And in the base theme folder the catalog.xml (and all other catalog.xml's I've seen) uses this to call it

```
<reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

I tried replacing the top one with the bottom one - no luck. Can't figure out how to get layered nav working in this new theme.

Any one encountered this issue before?

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution.

Under the Anchor category in the RWD theme's catalog.xml, change this

```
    <reference name="left_first">
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="catalog.leftnav.state.renderers" as="state_renderers" />
        </block>
    </reference>
```

to this

```
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="catalog.leftnav.state.renderers" as="state_renderers" />
        </block>
    </reference>
```

Yep, that is sadly all it took. No idea why _first was added there if it just causes layered nav to not function.

Comment: Well, something is not right there, because the original reference here is still `left_first` and I have all layered navigation working in untouched CE 1.9.

Comment: Could be an upgrade issue perhaps. This was 1.7 originally and had been upgraded to 1.9. With the _first removed though it all works perfectly now at least.

Comment: I believe the left_first block was added in 1.9 as a slot for left column items that should show above the main column content when the responsive theme collapses down to 1 column at small widths. (By default the rest of the "left" stuff shows below, which is not good for navigation.) I agree, sounds like an upgrade issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue, and I found a quick fix to it.

The problem is that the Navigation menu relies on a particular Root category and if you change the default category or create a new Root category the Navigation menu doesn’t recognize it without a little tweak. Here’s how you can fix it.

- From the Catalog Menu select Manage Categories
- Click Add Root Category
- Name your Root Category (root-SITENAME)
- On the General Information Tab ensure Is Active equals Yes
- On the General Information Tab ensure Include in Navigation Menu equals Yes
- Click Save Category
- With the new Root Category Selected click Add Subcategory
- Create the subcategory of the main category making sure it is Active and Included on the Nav Menu
- From the Main Menu Systems – Manage Stores
- Click the Main Website Store link
- From the Root Category drop-down choose the Root Category you created earlier (root-SITENAME)
- Click Save Store

Any new categories you create should appear on the Navigation Menu.

You can read more about in [here](http://www.acumensoftwaredesign.com/magento/magento-nav-menu-not-displaying)

Comment: thanks Nav this is useful but entirely unrelated to the question, the OP was asking about the layered nav that appears on the category pages not the dropdown menu